# Render JSON with Angular

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

Can someone please explain and show, how I can render a complex JSON object with Angular.

I am making a call to the FourSquare API which returns a list of recommended venues based on my search(location). The JSON file is huge and am finding it difficult to render out the relevant data in it.

Here is what my JSON looks like:
https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore#req=venues/explore%3Fnear%3DEarlsfield

Here is the function in my controller which makes a call to the url.
Note; baseurl = the url i built up with my AccessId and Secret

```
//Get response from server  
function fetch(){
  $http.get(baseurl + $scope.search)
   .success(function(response){ 
    console.log(response.response.groups[0].items);
    $scope.details = response; 

   });
```

I would then like to be able to render out my results in an ul with lis. Each LI would have the name of the venue as well as other information. At the moment I have the following:

```
     <div ng-if="!details">
            Loading...
        </div>

        <div ng-if="details.Response==='True'">
            <ul ng-repeat='groups in response'>
                <li>{{item.name}}</li>
                <li>{{item.address}}</li>

            </ul>
        </div>

        <div ng-if="details.Response==='False'">
          No results found.
        </div>
```

CODEPEN LINK:
http://codepen.io/AntonioVassilev/full/EVrKxp/

I am a novice in Angular and am finding it confusing browsing through large data objects like this one. Help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `details` is a Object and you can't loop on it. Fetch `groups` first: like `details.groups`

JSON structure: http://screencloud.net/v/Oqd

Some example:

```
 <ul ng-repeat='group in details.groups'>

            <li>{{group.name}}</li>
            <li>{{group.type}}</li>

            <ul ng-repeat='item in group.items'>

            <pre>{{item}}</pre>

        </ul>
```

<kbd>[Some demo you can play with](http://jsfiddle.net/brka0LdL/)</kbd>

Comment: Unfortunately I am still not able to access the name or type - I made a pen(added to the question above). that should give more conext

Comment: @AntonioVasilev I run the same URL and get data. Check what wrong with your code

Comment: @AntonioVasilev your fixed Codepan: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KdJzzX?editors=101

Comment: Gotcha! So if i was interested in the name, for example i would do item.venue.name. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score -1):

You should be repeating on your scope variable (scope.details). According to your js the correct ng-repeats seem to be sth like this:

```
<div ng-repeat='groups in details'>
  <div ng-repeat='group in groups'>
    <ul ng-repeat='item in group.items'>
        <li>{{item.name}}</li>
        <li>{{item.address}}</li>
    </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```